# Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLDivElement] - jQuery 1.6.2

Tags: jquery, syntax-error

I'm trying to get an A tag to appear after a delay but I'm getting this error message on hover:

> Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLDivElement]

This is the code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".folio_small").fadeTo('fast', 0.5);

        $(".folio_small").hover(
                function() {
                    $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1).delay(400);
                    $(this + ".info").fadeTo('slow', 1);
                },
                function() {
                    $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
                }
        )
    });
```

And this is an example of what I'm using it on:

```
<div class="folio_small">
    <a class="info" href="#">
        <p class="small">ILLUSTRATION</p>
    </a>
    <img src="images/portfolio/120x90_i1.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

I'm trying to select the .info class inside .folio_small (this). Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You cannot just concatenate a DOM element and a string...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".info",this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
```

OR

```
 $(this).children(".info").fadeTo('slow', 1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9QbGn/1/

**Explanation courtesy @Felix Kling**

You cannot just concatenate a DOM element and a string...

Comment: A bit of explanation would go nicely with the answer. :)

Comment: i was thinking the same but couldn't find the appropriate words, if you have it please edit the answer tnx `:)`

Comment: I think what you've now got is fine. :) Explanations don't need to be lengthy, just need to let people know which bit was actually wrong and needed replacing. :)